# How do I fix this error in python { LAT.append(float(row[6].strip())) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\\N' }?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a function to read in all the data from a .csv file and append each column to a list. However, when I try to convert the values in a certain column to a float, it gives me this error {LAT.append(float(row[6].strip())) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\N'}. Here is what I am working with:

```
ID = []
NAME = []
ADDRESS = []
POSTAL = []
EAST = []
NORTH = []
LAT = []
LON = []
AUTH = []


# read in data
def read_data():
    data = pd.read_csv('Pubs in England.csv', delimiter=',')
    for row in data.values:
        ID.append(row[0])
        NAME.append(row[1])
        ADDRESS.append(row[2])
        POSTAL.append(row[3])
        EAST.append(row[4])
        NORTH.append(row[5])
        LAT.append(float(row[6].strip()))
        LON.append(float(row[7].strip()))
        AUTH.append(row[8])
```

The LAT list is for all the latitude values in the .csv file and the LON list is for all the longitude values in the .csv file. Everything else works as intended.

Comment: What's the output of `print(row); break` in the loop?

Comment: @ForceBru it prints just the whole first row of the data frame
EDIT: If I do print(row) and don't break it prints every row with [] around it but still has the error.

Comment: yes, I was trying to get a sample of your dataframe to see where the `\N` could be coming from

Comment: `code`[24 'Anchor Inn' 'Upper Street, Stratford St Mary, COLCHESTER, Essex'
 'CO7 6LW' 604748 234405.0 '51.97039' '0.979328' 'Babergh'] this is the output

Comment: But you want to see the offending row, not the first one, so you could add this before the `LAT.append()` call: `if '\N' in row[6]: print(row)`. Or catch the error with a `try` and put the `print` call in the `except` clause.

Comment: @ChadMeyers, well, the first row looks fine. You could try printing all of them and see which one contains the `\N`. Maybe this row is malformed - AFAIK, latitude information isn't supposed to contain `\N`. Basically, your code looks fine, so it's likely the data (the CSV file) that's invalid

Comment: `[5501 'The Greenstone' 'Napier Way, Dereham, Norfolk' 'NR19 1FS' 622675
 -5527598.0 '\\N' '\\N' 'Breckland']` This is just one row it printed out, there are a bunch of them so I assume it is because the .csv file does not have a value for longitude and latitude for these places?

Comment: Yes, these `\N` values look like placeholders for missing values in that particular csv file. You can replace them with `np.nan`, which happens to be a float value, so your list will be consistent.

Comment: Okay what would the code look like to replace these values with np.nan?

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to compute the missing values from the `EAST` and `NORTH` values?

Comment: To replace them, you could do this within the loop: `if 'N' in row[6]: LAT.append(np.nan); else: LAT.append(float(row[6].strip()))`